# Volume optimization can

Tags: calculus

I'm stuck... The problem states that - You wish to construct a right cylindrical can (with bottom and top) from a square steel plate with side length 10 cm. What dimensions on r and h maximizes the volume of the can.

Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that the formula for the surface area of a right circular cylinder is $A=2\pi r h + 2 \pi r^2$:

$$
10^2=2\pi r h + 2 \pi r^2
$$

Then express $h$ as a function of $r$ and use the formula for the volume of a right circular cylinder:
$$
h(r)=\frac{50}{\pi r}-r\\
V(r)=\pi r^2 h(r) = \pi r^2 \left(\frac{50}{\pi r}-r \right)=50r-\pi r^3,\ 0\lt r\lt \sqrt\frac{50}{\pi}$$

Now, just find what $r$ makes the function $V(r)$ attain the maximum value. For that, set the first derivative of $V(r)$ equal to zero and solve for $r$: $V'(r)=50-3\pi r^2=0\implies r=\sqrt{\frac{50}{3\pi}}$. When you find the $r$, it's going to be trivial to find $h$: $h\left(\sqrt{\frac{50}{3\pi}}\right)$.

Comment: When i do this, i get the sqare root of A/6pi for r. Which is wrong apparently...

Comment: In fact, I think that the problem is much more difficult that it looks. $100$ is not the surface area of the can but the area of the plate ! Interesting problem.

Comment: Well, you have a square steel plate whose side is $10$ cm. Its area is going to be 100 square cementers. That's the amount of material that you're allowed to use to construct the surface area of the can. Am I not right?

Comment: You are correct, theres going to be excess steel.

Comment: according to  the answer in the book the r should be 5/π and h = 10(1-1/π). And i´m either retarded or blind. Because i can´t seem to get the right answer

Comment: Hmm, I do think I have set the problem up correctly.